# Placing divs side by side and adding elements in it

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have 3 divs side by side in a HTML document and I managed to achieve it where it looks something like this:

[image]

But whenever I tried adding objects such as text or any other objects, the div is always shifting down:

[image]

Could anyone help me out on this?

**Edit**
Thanks for the response but i forgot that i wanted a logo at the top left, then followed by the 3 divs below the logo, but adding "flex" property to the container leads to this:

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.input {
  width: 450px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.output {
  width: 650px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.output_2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!--
            this is the outermost shell
        -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- to add a logo at the top left -->
  <div class = "sun_lg">
        <img src = "images/sun.png" height = "50">
    </div>
  <div class="input">
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>

  <div class="output">

  </div>

  <div class="output_2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make your container flex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` to your container.
To learn more about flexbox read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

You can also use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  /* new  */
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  display: flex;
}

.input {
  width: 450px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.output {
  width: 650px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.output_2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* update for logo */

.sun_lg {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- to add a logo at the top left -->
  <div class="sun_lg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" height="50">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="input">
      <p>Hi</p>
    </div>

    <div class="output">

    </div>

    <div class="output_2">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: updated my post as i forgot that i needed a logo at the top left.

Comment: i've update my answer, is that what do you want?

Comment: yes, thank you! Also can i ask, do you think that using "display: inline-block" is the right way in order to align divs side by side? Previously i tried using "position:absolute" to align divs side by side but it turned to be a disaster when i started adding objects in it.

Comment: display: inline-flex does not make flex items display inline. It makes the flex container display inline.

Answer (score -1):

Define vertical-align to set the exact behavior of divs against texts baseline. I will use `vertical-align:top` in all child divs:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.input {
  width: 450px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.output {
  width: 650px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.output_2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 680px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<!--
            this is the outermost shell
        -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="input">
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>

  <div class="output">

  </div>

  <div class="output_2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but I've updated my post since i forgotten that i wanted a logo at the top left.

Comment: After you set `vertical-align` you can also add an inline image beside other divs. Using flex is not mandatory. @Maxxx